# How to populate a lookup field in custom object using Apex

Tags: custom-object, lookup

I am building an app which reads information from an external API and then populates data in my App for further processing. I have two kinds of custom objects for this. First kind (e.g., BasicProfile) stores all the retrieved information. And second kind (e.g., Summary) stores the derived information.

Summary also needs to have a lookup for BasicProfile and this is working fine in Salesforce UI. But when I try to populate this lookup field using Apex code, it is giving me error "Illegal assignment from BasicProfile__c to Id". Please let me know how can I populate the lookup field using Apex.

Following is my existing code in Apex. (If I remove the lookup part, everything else is working fine, both the objects are inserted separately.)

```
public BasicProfile__c getBasicProfile(Map<String, Object> basic_profile){
    BasicProfile__c obj = new BasicProfile__c();
    obj.Zip__c = (String)basic_profile.get('Zip');
    insert obj;
    return obj;
}

public PageReference doInsert() {
    Summary__c objdlt = new Summary__c();
    objdlt.Name__c = nameVal;

    # Get json response from external API

    Map<String, Object> m = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(json_response);

    Map<String, Object> basic_profile = (Map<String, Object>)m.get('BasicProfile');

    # THIS LINE
    objdlt.BasicProfile__c = getBasicProfile(basic_profile);
    insert objdlt; 

    pagereference ref = new pagereference(redirect_page);
    ref.setredirect(true);
    return ref;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
objdlt.BasicProfile__c = getBasicProfile(basic_profile).Id;
```

`getBasicProfile(basic_profile)` is returning the actual `BasicProfile__c` object, when you really just need its Id. So, access it via `Id`.

It makes more sense when you look at it this way:

```
BasicProfile__c profile = getBasicProfile(basic_profile);

objdlt.BasicProfile__c = profile.Id; // not profile,  a reference to an object, not an id
```

Maybe also rename `getBasicProfile` to `createBasicProfile`?